# PHP dependancy issue after upgrading to PHP 5.6.5

Tags: centos, php, yum

I'm trying to install Laravel, this required me to upgrade to php 5.6.5. This was a success and php is running fine, but im having 2 dependency issues when i try to install other packages that laravel requires such as php mbstring

```
yum install php-mbstring
...
Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 from updates
    php-mbstring-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 from updates
```

I thought that this meant php-common was out of date since it was 5.3.3 so i tried updating to the latest version and got this message.

```
yum install php56w-common

Package php56w-common-5.6.5-1.w6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Im still getting the same error. i tried removing the old 5.3.3 version of php-common, but it isnt installed.

My server is running centos 6.6

Update
Using the repo from the guide i was using 
https://iamtrishulpani.wordpress.com/2014/10/21/installing-and-using-laravel-4-2-on-centos-6-5/

I was able to get past this error, but now its telling me that it cant find XZ compression

Answer (score 2):

Resolved all of the issues by doing the following. First the issue with XZ seems to be an issue with rpm. The issue with the mbstring might have been a simple command error

```
wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

yum clean all

yum install php56w-mbstring
```